# Can't set React state when getting user lat/long location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I'm trying to get the user's location (that works) and set it to the current state in a React component (this part doesn't). I've looked through a few answers on here and can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I have:

```
class Container extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      location: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      }
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        let lat = position.coords.latitude
        let lng = position.coords.longitude
        console.log("getCurrentPosition Success " + lat + lng) // logs position correctly
        this.setState({
          location: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          }
        })
      },
      (error) => {
        this.props.displayError("Error dectecting your location");
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error))
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    )
  }
  render() {
    const location = this.state.location
    return (
      <div>
         <Map center={location}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It looks similar to what other people have, and I've tried a few different ways, but I can't get the state to set. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: what error do u get?

Comment: I don't get any error. It just doesn't update this.state.location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setState command is working fine.

[image]

Note that the get location is an async. call, and therefore the render() will be called twice. The first time it call, the lat/lng is zero.

You can add a logic to check it is zero and return null, if you want to render the output after getting the lat/lng from the geolocation services.

Comment: How would I do that? I tried   const location = (this.state.location == 0) ? null : this.state.location  but it didn't work

Comment: add this "if (location.lat == 0 && location.lng ==0) { return null; }" before the return() statement in render function.